# How do I specify which identity to use with vsts-npm-auth?

Tags: npm, azure-devops, vsts-npm-auth

I am trying to authenticate against an azure devops npm feed.
I can log into Azure with 2 different accounts, an old one that will eventually be deprecated and a new one, and I want to authenticate with the new account.

Now When I call
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -F -V Detailed

from the terminal, then I get the following output:

```
vsts-npm-auth v0.43.0.0
-----------------------
Parameters:
  AuthenticationProviders=msal,wia,federated
  Config=.npmrc
  Help=False
  NonInteractive=False
  TargetConfig=
  ExpirationMinutes=129600
  ReadOnly=False
  Force=True
  Verbosity=Detailed
INI (resolved): //<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/common/npm/registry/:username=VssSessionToken
INI (resolved): //<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/common/npm/registry/:_password=<redacted ---sekretz--->
INI (resolved): //<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/common/npm/registry/:email=<new mail>@<new>.de
INI (resolved): //<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/public/npm/registry/:username=VssSessionToken
INI (resolved): //<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/public/npm/registry/:_password=<redacted ---sekretz--->
INI (resolved): //<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/public/npm/registry/:email=<new mail>@<new>.de
INI (resolved): @public:registry=https://<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/public/npm/registry/
INI (resolved): @public:always-auth=true
INI (resolved): registry=https://<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/common/npm/registry/
INI (resolved): always-auth=true
Probing https://<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/common/npm/registry/
Probe response code: 401 Unauthorized
Credential type: Sps.
Authority url: https://login.windows.net/6b3e3388-6123-4327-aa06-2d82a999567d
Has valid credentials: False.
Getting new credentials for source:https://<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/common/npm/registry/, scope:vso.packaging_write vso.drop_write
Getting authentication token from https://vssps.dev.azure.com/<organization>/
Trying authentication provider Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)...
Using MSAL cache at C:\Users\<my user>\AppData\Local\.IdentityService
MSAL using WAM Broker
Found in cache: 6b3e3388-6123-4327-aa06-2d82a999567d\<old mail>@<old>.de
Found in cache: 5c7c1590-4488-4e42-bc9c-15218f8ac994\<new mail>@<new>.de
Attempting to use identity 6b3e3388-6123-4327-aa06-2d82a999567d\<old mail>@<old>.de     <------- Why the old? How can I change it to the new mail?
SPS CreateSessionToken Activity ID: ce5035db-f3e7-4805-8698-7edc0511f1a5
The acquired token is not a JWT.
Probing https://<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/public/npm/registry/
Probe response code: 401 Unauthorized
Credential type: Sps.
Authority url: https://login.windows.net/6b3e3388-6123-4327-aa06-2d82a999567d
Has valid credentials: False.
Getting new credentials for source:https://<organization>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/public/npm/registry/, scope:vso.packaging_write vso.drop_write
Getting authentication token from https://vssps.dev.azure.com/<organization>/
Trying authentication provider Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)...
MSAL using WAM Broker
Found in cache: 6b3e3388-6123-4327-aa06-2d82a999567d\<old mail>@<old>.de
Found in cache: 5c7c1590-4488-4e42-bc9c-15218f8ac994\<new mail>@<new>.de
Attempting to use identity 6b3e3388-6123-4327-aa06-2d82a999567d\<old mail>@<old>.de
SPS CreateSessionToken Activity ID: 16d0f103-58b7-4f8f-99cb-84210f32221a
The acquired token is not a JWT.
```

Note: I replaced the mails in the log-output with @.de
In line 35 you can see that the tool tries to use the old account to generate the tokens with and no matter what I do I can't get it to use or try the other account.

I tried:

- uninstalling the tool,
- Emptied the npm cache
- deleted the .npmrc file in my user directory
- deleted the Tokens in the Registry Path Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio
- restarted my machine and repeated the vsts auth command without and with force.

I tried emptying the browser cache to get rid of any cookies possibly interfereing

I tried to delete the msal-cache at "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\.IdentityService"

I "forgot" the other old account linked to my microsoft profile.

I am also not being prompted to select either one of these accounts even though interactive mode is enabled.

And I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem online.

I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what.
Can anyone tell me how I can make the switch to the new mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output log of the terminal, you are using the vsts-npm-auth version: 0.43.0.

I can reproduce the same issue when using the same version of the Tool.

It does not provide parameters to allow us to select the corresponding account to generate credentials, and we cannot change/reset existing credentials.

For a workaround, you can use the roll back to the previous version: **0.42.1**

Here are the steps:

1.Uninstall the existing vsts-npm-auth version.

`npm uninstall -g vsts-npm-auth`

2.Install the version:0.42.1.

`npm install -g vsts-npm-auth@0.42.1 --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false`

When you first use it, it will pop up a login box asking you to provide account credentials.

Then if you need to reset the credentials, you can navigate to Registry path and delete the existing token:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp`

[image]

When you re-run the command: `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -F -V Detailed`, it will force you to input the credential again.

For example:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, with that I was able to select an account.

After that I get a new error message at least:

Getting authentication token from ...
Trying authentication provider Windows Integrated Authentication via Azure AD...
Authorization failure while retrieving a session token
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://vssps.dev.azure.com.

The new accounts exist as guests inside our Azure AD since they belong to a different Domain. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @ViktorPagels Yes. I can see this error too. But the token still can be generated successfully and add to the .npmrc file.  It can work as expected. I think we can ignore this error. You can check if it can work for you when executing the npm command

Comment: Yes it is working. I think that it tries multiple authentication methods and the first one simply fails.